# Is itertools.combinations() deterministic?

Tags: python, functional-programming, combinatorics

Is the order of items obtained from itertools.combinations() deterministic?

I am currently writing a script which produces an excessively large number of objects using itertools.combinations, large enough that I can't retain it all in memory. For each combination, there is a function which returns a value that I store in a numpy array (since those are fairly memory efficient). I have just barely enough memory to store all of those floats.

I then iterate over those floats, and if it's an index of interest, I run itertools.combinations again with a counter variable to access the combination that produced that result (which only takes a few seconds).

I have tested this with various smaller datasets for which I have enough memory, and the entries all are the same in those cases, but I am worried that this is not a "safe" approach to doing what I want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

> Combinations are emitted in lexicographic sort order. So, if the input
>   iterable is sorted, the combination tuples will be produced in sorted
>   order.
>
> Elements are treated as unique based on their position, not on their
>   value. So if the input elements are unique, there will be no repeat
>   values in each combination.

Comment: Oh man, I can't believe I missed that part of the documentation! Thank you very much! I can't accept the answer because of the cooldown period right now, but I will be sure to in a few minutes.

Comment: @AmphotericLewisAcid - np. I literally just asked a question on SO for something I'd missed in the pandas documentation lol